# ASP.NEt Web API 2 SendEmailAsync not sending email?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following code for my register method of my AccountController of my ASP.Net Web-API2 Applicaiton:

```
    // POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
        // Send an email with this link
        string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

        // make sure token code is URLEncoded to make sure any special characters in code are allowed in URI to be created 
        //code = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);

        //create the URL to be put into the email
        var callbackUrl = new Uri(Url.Link("ConfirmEmailRoute", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }));

        //create Email
        string msgUserId = user.Id;
        string msgSubject = "Home Turf Network - Confirm your account";
        string msgBody = "Please confirm your Home Turf Network account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>";

        //send email
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(msgUserId, msgSubject, msgBody);

        return Ok();
        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = user.Id }, user);
    }
```

It creates the user successfully, creates the code, callbackURL and from what I can tell everything that is needed for an email to go out to the registered user.  But the Email never goes out....

I have tested the callbackUrl that gets created and it does register the email in the DB successfully after it is put into a browser.  If the email would send out it would work perfectly.

I tried putting a breakpoint in my IdentityConfig where my EmailService gets set up and it never gets triggered when I debug the application and I can't figure out why it won't send out the email.

Here is my EmailService in my IdentityConfig.cs:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        //plug in your Email Service here to send an email
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"], message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body);
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"))
        {
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"] );
            client.Port = 587;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            client.Send(msg);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Any help tracing this issue out will be much appreciated.

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: my suggestion would be try removing async and await